# Luggage through check on domestic-domestic-international flight

Tags: transit, american-airlines, lax, abu-dhabi, las

I'll be travelling from Las Vegas to Abu Dhabi this end of July. I booked the ticket via American airlines website. There is a connection via Los Angeles, and the itinerary mentions that the flight from LAX to Abu Dhabi is American Airlines but operated by Etihad airways. My question was that do I need to re-check my baggage at LAX or does AA check my baggage from Las Vegas to Abu Dhabi?

Answer (score 4):

Your bag will be through-checked from Las Vegas to Abu Dhabi without needing to be claimed and re-checked.

AA and Etihad work together closely on travel between the USA and the Gulf.

Comment: Right.... Thanks, can you also help me with the mapping of LAX. The itinerary does mention about a terminal change and to my knowledge American Airlines land at terminal 4. How would I transfer to the International terminal from t-4. P.S: This will be my first time transiting via LAX). Regards

Comment: @AmmarKhalid You have two options. You can try to get on the airside bus between T4 and TBIT. If you use that, you don't need to go through security again. However that is actually only supposed to be for Qantas passengers (Qantas paid for the bus) so you are not really supposed to use it, but if you are quick and confident sometimes you can just get on!! Otherwise you need to exit the terminal and walk over to TBIT. It's a five minute walk, no bus. Once at TBIT, you need to go through security again.
In early 2016, a tunnel will open between the two terminals, with no security rescreen.